# Node.js TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever I execute my program, I receive the following `TypeError`:

```
/home/Node-Project/node_modules/sentiment/lib/index.js:31
        afinn = Object.assign(afinn, inject);
                       ^
TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'
    at module.exports (/home/Node-Project/node_modules/sentiment/lib/index.js:31:24)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/Node-Project/twit4.js:17:9)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at EventEmitter.processTweet (/home/Node-Project/node_modules/ntwitter/lib/twitter.js:242:14)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at EventEmitter.receive (/home/Node-Project/node_modules/ntwitter/lib/parser.js:44:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/Node-Project/node_modules/ntwitter/lib/twitter.js:258:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
```

I searched but I am unable to understand this error.

Do I have to install a special module?

Do I have to update Node or npm?

Is there an error in my program?

Here is my program:

```
var twitter = require('ntwitter');
var credentials = require('./credentials3.js');
var sentiment = require ('sentiment');

var twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: credentials.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: credentials.consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: credentials.access_token_key,
    access_token_secret: credentials.access_token_secret
});

twit.stream('statuses/filter',{ 'locations':'loc'}, 
function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
        var twitterSentiment, geoColor;
        sentiment(tweet.text, function (err, result) {
            twitterSentiment = result;
            if (result == 0) {
                geoColor = '#B5B5B5';
            } else if (result < 0) {
                geoColor = '#FC0828';
            } else {
                geoColor = '#00DE1E';
            } console.log(result);              
            });

        });
    });
```

Can someone please shed some light?

Comment: *"Do I have to update Node"* Most likely. Which version do you use? Have a look at http://node.green/ to see if your version supports `Object.assign`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only Node.js v4 and above has `Object.assign` built in.

If you're using an older version of Node, you can use a polyfill like [object.assign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object.assign).

Comment: Better to just update to a more modern version of node.js.

Answer (score 4):

Getting this kind of error in Cordova project, adding this code has fixed my problem;

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
    Object.assign = function (target, varArgs) {
        'use strict';
        if (target == null) {
            throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
        }
        var to = Object(target);
        for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
            var nextSource = arguments[index];

            if (nextSource != null) {
                for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
                        to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
                    }
                }
            }
         }
         return to;
    };
}
```

source: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova/issues/46#issuecomment-311923820

Answer (score 0):

May be I am too late. I have faced the same issue and sort it out like below. Download and install the latest version of the node from nodejs.org website. refer the video https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node
and check node version (node -v), hope it should be v6+. Hope it resolves your issue.