# npm - Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'

Tags: node.js, object, npm, typeerror

First of all, I did see the similar documents:

[Node.js TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477678/node-js-typeerror-object-function-object-native-code-has-no-method-ass)

[TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'method'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079080/typeerror-object-function-object-native-code-has-no-method-method)

However..

I am using node version 0.10.48 (my app uses deprecated node api so I rather stay on this version).

whenever I try to install a new module, or even run scripts that require modules, I receive the following error:
typeerror object function object() native code has no method 'assign'

I cannot even use npm v  or npm install/uninstall..

How do I get rid of this error? I simply cannot do anything on the terminal :(

Comment: I would try reinstalling Node 0.10.48 so that it ensures you have the correct version of `npm`. Also make sure you're not trying to install modules that don't support 0.10.48

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I cannot install anything.. any time I'm trying to use npm XXX i get this error (sudo does not help)

Comment: were you upgrading an old version?

Comment: From your browser, download the installer... in 0.10.48, you cannot use `npm install npm`, you must install it alongside Node

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh, haven't tought about that. I've installed the file and got in the 'bin/' folder 'node' exectuable and 'npm' files. How do I install this files?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#osx

```
curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-${VERSION:-$(wget -qO- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | sed -nE 's|.*>node-(.*)\.pkg</a>.*|\1|p')}.pkg" > "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" && sudo installer -store -pkg "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" -target "/"
```

Worked for me on Amazon Linux as well (different command).

issues17886 (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17996)